# Check for a certificate in the Firefox certificate storage

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, certificate, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

I am looking for a way to programmatically search for all certificates issued by a specific issuer in the firefox certificate storage and show their contents, like 'Username' and other fields on a web browser. All I found while searching the internet was options of how to load certificates into the storage, but not the other way round. Do you have an idea of how to do this? Is there any API out there which can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to achieve this with a firefox-addon? or you are trying to make a java applet to do so?

Comment: A java applet would be more of what I am looking for. Specifically I want to make a webpage where a user can look at his certificates issued by a specific issuer.

Comment: With java applets it's possible... however I recommend you the applets only if it's your unique way  because work with applets it's more complicated each day. If you want to do it through firefox sdk addons I can't help you.

Comment: I'm confused by the comments: Do you want to know how to do it via [tag:firefox-addon]/[tag:firefox-addon-sdk]? Or do ou want it via java applet? Your question never mentions java applets, only your comments do.

Comment: I never said that I want to have it done explicitly with java applets, any way works as long as it programmatically.